# Problem implementing a 2 levels association using rails3-amf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amf

I'm using https://github.com/warhammerkid/rails3-amf , and can't implement a two level association as follows:

```
@posts = Post.where(:category_id => params[:id]).includes(:author => :phones)

respond_with(@posts) do |format|
  format.amf { render :amf => @posts.to_amf( :include => ???? ) }
end
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails3-amf is deprecated. Look here:

https://github.com/rubyamf/rubyamf